# Error 401 Unauthorized when invoking Cloud Function despite granting roles

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-functions, jwt, httprequest

I have been trying to solve this on my own but have not been able to do it.
I made a simple cloud function (1st gen) that should give the message "hello world"

```
def hello_world(request): 
    return 'Hello World'
```

I name it function-test-3 and deploy.
Then I made another function from which I want to invoke this function and pass required authorization parameters through headers in a requests call.

```
import google.oauth2.id_token
import google.auth.transport.requests
import requests

endpoint = 'https://us-central1-sport-app-395020.cloudfunctions.net/function-test-3'

def make_authorized_get_request(endpoint):
    auth_req = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
    id_token = google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token(auth_req, endpoint)
    header_1 = {'Authorization':'Bearer '+id_token}
    response = requests.get(url=endpoint,headers=header_1)
    return str(response.content)
```

Then I get 401 error. I don't know what else to do, I have given owner, function invoker, function admin, and a plethora of other roles to the service account that has to invoke the functions, both in the called function and the caller one. This does not seem to solve the problem.

If I print an id token through the cli and literally paste the string in the header of the request, then it works.

I would like this to work without a json file. Because I have seen some methods that use that.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Edit 1:

**New service account id:**

```
new-service-account@sport-app-395020.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

**gcloud functions describe function-test-3**

```
availableMemoryMb: 256
buildId: d638badd-4a78-41f7-bb95-9a7c97561e0b
buildName: projects/445319123164/locations/us-central1/builds/d638badd-4a78-41f7-bb95-9a7c97561e0b
dockerRegistry: CONTAINER_REGISTRY
entryPoint: hello_world
httpsTrigger:
  securityLevel: SECURE_OPTIONAL
  url: https://us-central1-sport-app-395020.cloudfunctions.net/function-test-3
ingressSettings: ALLOW_ALL
labels:
  deployment-tool: console-cloud
  maxInstances: 3000
  name: projects/sport-app-395020/locations/us-central1/functions/function-test-3
  runtime: python310
serviceAccountEmail: new-service-account@sport-app-395020.iam.gserviceaccount.com
sourceUploadUrl: https://storage.googleapis.com/uploads-890291164480.us-central1.cloudfunctions.appspot.com/d00981be-b7cb-42b9-b443-85b7d1f0c29b.zip
status: ACTIVE
timeout: 60s
updateTime: '2023-08-09T01:11:03.263Z'
versionId: '3'
```

**gcloud functions get-iam-policy function-test-3**

```
bindings:
- members:
  - serviceAccount:sport-app-395020@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/cloudfunctions.admin
- members:
  - serviceAccount:new-service-account@sport-app-395020.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  - serviceAccount:sport-app-395020@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/cloudfunctions.invoker
etag: BwYCcvpm7fc=
version: 1
```

**gcloud functions describe doom-function-2**

```
availableMemoryMb: 256
buildId: 669735af-ecb6-47de-b57b-a01119eed5b7
buildName: projects/445319123164/locations/us-central1/builds/669735af-ecb6-47de-b57b-a01119eed5b7
dockerRegistry: CONTAINER_REGISTRY
entryPoint: make_authorized_get_request
httpsTrigger:
  securityLevel: SECURE_OPTIONAL
  url: https://us-central1-sport-app-395020.cloudfunctions.net/doom-function-2
ingressSettings: ALLOW_ALL
labels:
  deployment-tool: console-cloud
maxInstances: 3000
name: projects/sport-app-395020/locations/us-central1/functions/doom-function-2
runtime: python310
serviceAccountEmail: new-service-account@sport-app-395020.iam.gserviceaccount.com
sourceUploadUrl: https://storage.googleapis.com/uploads-890291164480.us-central1.cloudfunctions.appspot.com/c1312040-cb2c-4532-ad15-c33d637bb8d3.zip
status: ACTIVE
timeout: 60s
updateTime: '2023-08-09T01:08:10.996Z'
versionId: '29'
```

**gcloud functions get-iam-policy doom-function-2**

```
bindings:
- members:
  - allUsers
  - serviceAccount:sport-app-395020@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/cloudfunctions.invoker
etag: BwYCYOllrBQ=
```

version: 1

**Actual error message:**

```
Error: Unauthorized
Your client does not have permission to the requested URL function-test-3
```

I looked the token before in jwt decoder and it is a valid token, though it does not work, this is its content

```
{
    "header":
    {
        "alg":"RS256"
        "kid":"911e39e27928ae9f1e9d1e21646de92d19351b44"
        "typ":"JWT"
    }

    "payload":
    {
        "aud":"<Request 'http://us-central1-sport-app-395020.cloudfunctions.net/' [GET]>"
        "azp":"113939113937084571622"
        "email":"new-service-account@sport-app-395020.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
        "email_verified":true
        "exp":1691553146
        "iat":1691549546
        "iss":"https://accounts.google.com"
        "sub":"113939113937084571622"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new service account. Do not assign it any roles. Make note of the email address.
2. Go to  the Google Cloud Console GUI. Go to Cloud Functions. Click on the function name function-test-3.
3. Click on the PERMISSIONS tab.
4. Click GRANT ACCESS. Enter the email address of the new service account. Select Cloud Functions Invoker role and save. You have now authorized the service account.
5. Go to the other function that will be calling function-test-3.
6. Click EDIT AND REDPLOY.
7. Change the Runtime Service Account to the new service account.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answers. Still does not work. Same error 401 status code "Your client does not have permission to the requested URL". I think that something might be wrong in the way I am fetching the IdToken, but dont know what.

Comment: @RafaelPabon - you are leaving out an important detail OR most likely you are not configuring correctly. Edit your post and include the output from these commands for both of your functions: `gcloud functions describe FUNCTION_NAME` and `gcloud functions get-iam-policy FUNCTION_NAME`. Show the command and output formatted to make everything easy to read. Include the identity of the new service account that you created.

Comment: @RafaelPabon - include the actual error message.

Comment: @RafaelPabon - add a print statement for the `id_token`. Then go to Cloud Functions logs and make sure you have a valid token. It will be an OIDC Identity Token.

Comment: edited with the requested info, included the payload of the token, i think that maybe there could be something wrong with the aud value?

Comment: I updated your post's formatting. In the token `payload`, this line looks strange: `"aud":"<Request 'http://us-central1-sport-app-395020.cloudfunctions.net/' [GET]>"`. How did you print the token? The `aud` should be `https://us-central1-sport-app-395020.cloudfunctions.net/function-test-3`.

Comment: @RafaelPabon - As a test try this example Python code: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#generating_tokens_programmatically

Comment: Hi again, I had already checked that script before, but previously I did not look into the log of errors. It seems that you can't pass audience as a parameter when defining the function, not sure why. Because I did not look at the log, I followed a large and unnecessary path that made me use requests insted of urlllib. Even though I removed audience as a parameter, because I was using requests, the call did not work (not sure why requests does not work). But finally, now it works. Thanks for the answers.